# Cutting a sphere in 18 parts of equal size with some planes?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to divide this sphere into $18$ parts of equal size using ssome palnes?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: can you factor 18 ?

Comment: I was pointing out that you can at very least use it's factors to get to 18 parts ( if not exactly equal).

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: How?

Comment: 18= 2*3*3 to divide a line into n distinct sections you need n-1 dividers that means you can use 2 dividers to partition one dimension into 3, 2 more for the second dimension into 3, and 1 more to cut the third dimension in half. and that will give 18 pieces ( not necessarily equal).

Comment: There are actually two ways (at least) of cutting the space in 18 pieces: the one you describe in (3*3)*2 (looks like # ), but also the (3*2)*3 "star" version $*$,  where 3 planes intersect along the same line, and then 2 more parallel planes cut these 6 volumes.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277542/cutting-a-sphere-in-18-parts-of-equal-size-with-only-5-planes – you really shouldn't do that. And if you do it, you really, really should mention that you're doing it.

Answer (score 2):

The planes $z=0,\,z=\sqrt{3}x,\,z=-\sqrt{3}x$ have common intersection the $y$-axis and cut the unit sphere into six congruent "orange slices."

The two planes $y\approx \pm0.22607$ perpendicular to the $y$-axis cut the unit sphere into three parts having equal volume, simultaneously slicing each of those "orange slices" into three parts of equal volume thereby cutting the unit sphere into 18 parts of equal volume.

The number $0.22607$ is the approximate value of $c$ in the integral

$$ \int_c^1\pi z^2dy=\int_c^1\pi(1-y^2)\,dy=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{4\pi}{3} $$